# Trying to figure out the equivalent of C++ arrays in Python

Tags: python

My code is:

```
for X in range(16):
    appleX = 0
    middleTileX = -350 + (distance/2)
    appleX[X] += middleTileX + distance*X
```

and I'm trying to get a list of 16 numbers and store them on appleX, I then want to run so that a randomizer will pick a random number on the list (let's say number 5) and then it will look on the 5th stored number in the "array" or list in python. The 5th number should be the answer of

```
     middleTileX + distance*5
```

but I don't want to calculate and write all of the 16 numbers and I have found no way of automatically assigning values to a list.

I haven't tried much as none of the answers on the internet seems to be the right one

Comment: Maybe it's time for a better search engine, because a decent one would turn up 'list comprehensions' in Python. After `mtx = -350 + (distance/2)` all that is needed is `apple_x = [mtx + distance * x for x in range(16)]` and then you can just `apple_x[randint(0, 16)]`

Comment: Your code won't run as-is, because you first create the object `appleX` as an int - `0` - and not a list. Use `appleX = []` instead. Also, you don't need to specify the index when assigning values to the list. Just use the `.append()` method, or as Grismar suggests, use a list comprehension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need **list comprehension**.

> *I'm trying to get a list of 16 numbers and store them on appleX, I
> then want to run so that a randomizer will pick a random number on the
> list (let's say number 5) and then it will look on the 5th stored
> number in the "array" or list in python.*

```
result = [middleTitleX + distance*i for i in range(16)]
```

Comment: ohh that makes so much sense, weird how I didn't find list comprehension but maybe I was searching for the wrong thing.